# Не получается отправить данные о пользователе на сервер. Firebase+react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Я не понимаю, что с этим кодом не так.Он то работает, то не работает.Задача состоит в том, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку зарегистрироваться в firebase добавлялся бы пользователь(это кстати работает стабильно), а далее на сервер отправляются данные о пользователе.

```
 async register(name, surname, email, password) {
    await this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

        return app.database().ref('users/').push({
            name: name,
            surname: surname,
            id: this.auth.currentUser.uid,
            email: email,
        });     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема решалась очень просто, мне нужно было дописать event.preventDefault)